# Using ipfw with Apple's Reachability class

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, reachability, ipfw

Do packet filter rules specified with ipfw affect the working of Apple's Reachability class ?

For eg. If I enforce these rules:

```
sudo ipfw add 120 deny tcp from me to www.google.co.in
sudo ipfw add 130 deny tcp from www.google.co.in to me
```

and run this code:

```
Reachability* hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.co.in"];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];
```

the netStatus returned is *ReachableViaWiFi* while I was expecting *NotReachable*. Is the Reachability bypassing the firewall ?